# js toggle and button

Tags: javascript, dropdownbox

I made this JS spoiler and it works fine if I have only one drop down box, but if I try to add more than one spoiler in the page, than when I click on the second spoiler link it opens the first spoiler. Than I changed the id "hidden" of second link to "hidden2" and it worked as I wanted it to work. 
The problem is with the linked image which I use as a spoiler opening and closing button. (When  click on the image I want it to change to other image. ) So, when I click on one button to open spoiler the image changes on both first spoiler button and second....
Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/884mC/3/) to understand what I mean.. Click on the second button.....

```
function toggle(element) {
    if (document.getElementById(element).style.display == "none") {
    document.getElementById(element).style.display = "";
    document.getElementById("drop").src="/drop_up.png";

    } else {
    document.getElementById(element).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("drop").src="/drop_down.png";

    }
    } 


    <a href="javascript:toggle('hidden')"><img  id="drop" width="25px" src="/drop_down.png" /></a>
    <div id="hidden" style="display:none;">
    Box content
    </div>
```

Comment: Because in JS, where src is changing, you are selecting ID: drop, but browser select first element with that ID. Did you try jQuery? It could makes your code simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because this:

```
document.getElementById("drop").src
```

Is ambiguous. You shouldn't have two elements with identical IDs on a page - use a class if there are multiple instances of the same name. Javascript is just searching until it finds the first instance of the 'drop' id, and stopping.